# Not able to set path on VS Code terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Don't know why VS Code is fetching the path which I haven't even set. Please help... I am a beginner.

My project's parent folder is on Desktop and I have set the path accordingly on VS Code's terminal, and I use bash. To run the JS code I am using Node.
But here is the trick, the path which I've set is perfectly shown on the terminal and so after giving commands to run the file using node, earlier it used to work properly but now it throws an error stating "Cannot find module" and shows a different path where I haven't even saved my file and folders.

It has to be found on 'C:\Users...' but now it is directing on 'C:\Program Files...'

PFB the error message.

````
$ node /02Basics/08ConditionalRoles.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\02Basics\08ConditionalRoles.js'```
````

Comment: Hi @Nidhi, you have this error probably not because your terminal targeting wrong place but instead your imports are? Does your code imports/requires files?

Comment: The terminal couldn't fetch the correct address where the file (consists code) was actually stored. Got answered by @Samathingamajig, and I am glad to see that the trick worked..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using just a `/`, Git Bash interprets that as the directory `/`, which is located at `C:\Program Files\Git\`. If you want to use local pathing, include a `.` at the beginning. This tells bash to start at the current working directory.

TLDR: Use this and it should work:

```sh
./02Basics/08ConditionalRoles.js
```